How to Change Calendar Background Color Between Light and Dark Mode
I'm working on a project that uses a default calendar component, and I need to implement dynamic background color changes when switching between light and dark themes. Specifically, I want the background color of the calendar to switch from white in light mode to black in dark mode.
Here is a screenshot of the current calendar view: 
I want to achieve this color switch based on the user's selected theme. How can I dynamically update the calendar's background color when switching between light and dark modes?
Questions:

What is the best approach to implement theme-based background color switching for a calendar
component?
Are there any specific libraries or techniques that make it easier to apply dynamic theming to
calendar components?


Please read [ask]. First of all your question misses debugging details. Then you ask two questions in one (missing focus). Your first question is opinion-based and the second one is asking for external libraries (Seeking tools, libraries, etc.). All of that a close reasons!

This example looks similar to your question. As you said, you can use various libraries. For example, I am developing on PrimeReact with React. There, the calendar component changes color according to light mode and dark mode. There are various libraries available, you can research. Another example is Flatpicker. You can examine the examples and choose the one that suits you best.
